# How to retrieve key with value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angular-ngmodel

When I submit a form, one of the fields being submitted is an ID (number) instead of the name for easier processing by the server. Like so:

HTML dropdown select

```
<select ng-model="myColor" class="form-control"
    ng-options = "color.ID as color.color for color in $parent.colorSelection">
</select>
```

AngularJS

```
$scope.colorSelection = [{"color": "Red", "ID": "7011"}, {"color": "Blue", "ID": "7012"}];
```

So the server sends a JSON back

```
res.json({
    Color: req.query.color, 
});
```

And now when I get the results back, I want to display the name instead of the ID number which is what the server sends back to me. So instead of showing "7011", I want to show "Red". How do I do this? Doing the following doesn't work.

```
{{results.Color.color}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `colorSelection` is an array, you'll have to loop through it, directly or by using one of the array functions that does.

In this case, `find` is probably what you want (you may need a shim on older browsers, if Angular doesn't already shim it for you):

```
var entry = $scope.colorSelection.find(function(entry) { return entry.ID == results.Color.color; });
var color = entry && entry.color;
```

`color` will be either `null` (not found) or the color name.

It's a bit less clunky with ES2015:

```
let entry = $scope.colorSelection.find(entry => entry.ID == results.Color.color);
let color = entry && entry.color;
```

---

Another approach would be to have a reusable map of color IDs to names:

In ES5, you'd probably use an object:

```
// One-time initialization of the map, just after you create
// $scope.colorSelection
$scope.colorSelectionMap = Object.create(null);
$scope.colorSelection.forEach(function(entry) {
    $scope.colorSelectionMap[entry.ID] = entry.color;
});
```

then

```
var color = $scope.colorSelectionMap[results.Color.color];
```

In ES2015, you could still do that, or you could use a `Map`:

```
// One-time initialization of the map, just after you create
// $scope.colorSelection
$scope.colorSelectionMap = new Map(
    $scope.colorSelection.map(entry => [entry.ID, entry.color])
);
```

then

```
var color = $scope.colorSelectionMap.get(results.Color.color);
```

Comment: would you show the other approach? My array is actually really large as this is just an example of what I am trying to do

Comment: Also I would put the code in my controller or HTML?

Comment: @jebmarcus: Done. I don't understand your question about where to put it, though; hopefully the update clarifies that for you anyway.

Comment: would you mind if we talk in more details in a chat?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below code for select

```
<select ng-model="myColor" class="form-control"
ng-options = "colorSelection as colorSelection.color for colorSelection in colorSelection ">
```

Comment: this doesn't work with {{results.Color.color}} or {{results.Color}} because with this way, the entire {"color": "Red", "ID": "7011"} shows up for results

Comment: $scope.colorSelection = [{"color": "Red", "ID": "7011"}, {"color": "Blue", "ID": "7012"}];  this work this json

Comment: when I call {{results.Color}}, I get {"color": "Red", "ID": "7011"}

Comment: tell me your all json value which store in  "results" variable

Comment: it's just $scope.results = data; in the controller and res.json({
    Color: req.query.color, 
}); in the server